# How do you initialize application state at startup and access it from controllers in MVC 6?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Let's say I have a class called `MySiteConfiguration` in which I have a bunch of, you guessed it, configuration data. This data will not change over the course of the application's runtime after it has been loaded.

My goal would be to construct an instance of this class at startup and access it from my controller actions. I do not want to construct the class more than once, as this should not be needed.

To do this in WebApi 2 for instance, I would:

1. Instantiate the class in my application start method.
2. Store the instance on the HttpConfiguration.Properties
3. Create a `ControllerBase` class which inherits from `ApiController`.
4. Override the `Initialize(HttpControllerContext)` method in my `ControllerBase` class. This override would read the configuration instance from `HttpControllerContext.Configuration.Properties` and assign it to a property / field in `ControllerBase`.

Any controller needing access to the configuration instance would inherit `ControllerBase` and reference the base property. Not so bad...

With that said, this pattern does not work in the new framework from what I can tell. There is no initialize method to override on MVC 6's new `Controller` class. I'm also not familiar enough with the new Startup.cs patterns and middleware available to know where to start with this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dependency injection. Register a singleton service that has your data, and then use constructor injection on your controllers to acquire the service instance.

First, define a service. A service can really be any class or interface.

```
public class MyConfigService {
    // declare some properties/methods/whatever on here
}
```

In your `Startup.cs` do something like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<MyConfigService>();
```

(Note that there are other overloads of `AddSingleton` depending on your scenario.)

And then consume it in each controller:

```
public MyController : Controller {
    public MyController(MyConfigService myService) {
        // do something with the service (read some data from it, store it in a private field/property, etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. What if the service to register in the singleton method is environment dependent? For instance, `ConfigService` might be my abstract implementation and I'd want to have concrete versions `DevelopmentConfigService` & `ProductionConfigService` registered depending on the runtime environment. Do you know how I'd achieve this?

Comment: Just use an `if()` statement to conditionally register the service implementation that you want. You can get the environment info from the `IApplicationEnvironment` interface. The `ConfigureServices` method itself can optionally take that as a parameter and it will get injected in.

Comment: Great, got this working. One last question, which might be best for another SO question, but to keep the context here -- how does one change the environment name present on the IHostingEnvironment object that gets injected? I don't see it being sourced from anywhere in my project like project.json for example. Thanks again.

Comment: In the latest builds set an env var `ASPNET_ENV` to the environment you want. In slightly older builds it was `KRE_ENV`. Check out an example here: https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/d9148bd6f768e6b3331f83824eb9d2280236d08a/src/MusicStore/Startup.cs#L87L89

Answer (score -2):

How about using the application state to store your configuration data?

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Application["MySiteConfiguration"] = new MySiteConfiguration();
}
```

You can then access your configuration data from inside your controllers.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var config = HttpContext.Application["MySiteConfiguration"] as MySiteConfiguration;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works in _MVC 6_. There is no longer an `Application_Start()`. It has been replaced with `Startup(IHostingEnvironment)`. In the context of this new method, there is no `Application' dictionary to set state on.